# When I switch desktops with multiple displays, why is the focus on the main display is changing to the same application on the current display?

Tags: display, google-chrome, iterm, mission-control

I am experiencing a weird issue. I have one external monitor and Macbook. I have multiple desktops on both displays. If I open an application, especially iTerm, Chrome, VSCode on the external monitor, another window of the same application is opening in my Mac display. This is only happening to iTerm, Chrome, and VSCode. I tried with Pycharm, Firefox, Brave browser they are working fine.

To understand it in a better way, consider this scenario

on Mac Display, I have these windows

Mac Desktop:

1. Chrome
2. iTerm
3. Mail
4. VSCode

on External Display

1. VSCode
2. iTerm
3. Chrome
4. Firefox

Say, Initially I have Mail in the Mac display and Firefox in the External Display.

I switched to iTerm / Chrome / VSCode in the External Display, the same window is appearing in the Mac Display.

I don't want this behavior, I want a window to be fixed in my Mac Display. How can I achieve that?

[image: mission control settings]
These are my Mission Control settings

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm understanding what you mean; but a couple of things to consider - 1) Displays have separate Spaces means that either display can be used to show any of your Spaces. Spaces are not fixed to a particular display. 2) Spaces is not designed to be able to handle the same app spread across more than one Space - you have both iTerm & Chrome on two different Spaces.

Comment: okay, so according to point number 2, all the windows of a single app should be present in a single space ?

Comment: Yes. You **can** move them to separate Spaces, but then switching Spaces &/or apps will become unpredictable.

Comment: This same issue is also happening for me, and in particular, the focus on mac will change only when I **switch desktops** on the **external display**.